# why is this code showing cannot find module error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

inside localbase.js...

```
const fs = require("fs");

if(!fs.existsSync(__dirname + "/localbase.json")) 
  fs.writeFileSync("./localbase.json", "{}");

let database = require("./localbase.json");
```

This above code is showing this error `Error: Cannot find module './localbase.json'`.

The file is imported in `server.js` as follows.

```
const lb = require('./db/localbase.js');
```

my directory structure (apology if my tree looks bad)...

```
|- db
+--- localbase.js
|- node_modules
|- public
server.js
package.json
```

But if I put the localbase.js where the server.js is then it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the fix is real simple...

```
const fs = require("fs");

if(!fs.existsSync(__dirname + "/localbase.json")) 
  fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/localbase.json", "{}");

let database = require(__dirname + "/localbase.json");
```

So basically what I did is I imported relative the root directory(where the node_modules is) which was causing that error.

I thought using `require('./localbase.json')` would choose the directory relative to `server.js` but it won't.

> So what I learnt is `require()` uses paths relative to root directory.
>
> Which means I have to use `__dirname` to import modules inside of sub-directories.